# DestinationPageUrl not working first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

I'm working with visual studio 2010.

I’ve put a login component on my page, when I try log my user for first time, the page redirect me to page log again, then I log again and works fine. I don't write the password wrong because it's remember by Chrome.

ASP code:

```
<asp:Login ID="lgnLogin" runat="server" BorderColor="#39516B" BorderPadding="0"
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Height="203px" Width="450px" 
                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#182B39" RememberMeText="Save password" 
                    style="text-align: center" BackColor="#E7EAEF" DisplayRememberMe="False" 
                    OnAuthenticate="lgnLogin_Authenticate" DestinationPageUrl="~/bandejaEntrada.aspx">
</asp:Login>
```

C# code:

```
protected void lgnLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            //Clear session
            Session.Clear();

            // Create new session
            CSessionUser oSesUser = new CSessionUser();
            e.Authenticated = oSesUser.BInitSession(lgnLogin.UserName, lgnLogin.Password);
            CLogger.MsgInfo("authen: " + e.Authenticated.ToString());

            CSesionSrv oSesionSrv = new CSesionSrv();
            oSesionSrv.BGuardar(lgnLogin.UserName);

            //lgnLogin.DestinationPageUrl = "~/bandejaEntrada.aspx";
            //Response.Redirect("~/bandejaEntrada.aspx",false);
            //Response.Redirect(ResolveClientUrl(lgnLogin.DestinationPageUrl));                
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            CLogger.MsgError("Web:login.aspx.cs:lgnLogin_Authenticate", ex);
        }
 }
```

The e.Authenticated properties alway is true, even the first time when page redirect me to login page again.

What causes this behavior?

Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: I see that sometime when I login in the website the first url has "login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWEBSITE%2f". Why add the param ReturnUrl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I modify Default Document in IIS, I put login.aspx at the end of the list and I put bandejaEntrada.aspx at the top of the list. Now when the param login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWEBSITE%2f appear in browser it´s redirect to bandejaEntrada instead the login page again.